# Vetctorizing recursion or iteration in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Let's say I have a vector v with elements 1...n, and I know that v(1) = v_0, and then

```
v(i+1) = 1/(a*v(i) + b).
```

This is straightforward to implement using either a single for loop, or recursion. Recursion is a terrible idea in Matlab, and the single foor loop is still not optimal if possible. Can I vectorize such a operation?

And to make this post more useful, is there a general way to vectorize

```
v(i+1) = f(v(i)),
```

where f(x) is an arbitrary function? What about something like

```
v(i+1) = a(i)*v(i) + b(i)
```

where a, and b are now vectors.

Comment: Vectorizing is for "parallelizing" a similar operation on all elements of a vector - here, the result of one cell depends on all the cells before it, so vectorization is not the way to go here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `for` loop is not as bad in MATLAB as it used to be, due to just-in-time compilation.  When in doubt, just write the loop and continue with your work.  Unless your vectors are gigantic, the loop won't bother you in the slightest.  If (and only if) the loop is a bottleneck, go back and try silly MATLAB tricks to optimize.

In a specific answer to your question, no, I do not believe there's a generic way to express v(i+1) = f(v(i)).  You could easily write one using a function handle, but the performance would be something less than just open-coding the expression.

Comment: I was worried about that. In this case, the largest bottleneck is a more complicated version of the original question. This is then looped many times, so a small speedup would result in a noticeable increase in speed. I figured there wasn't a way, but it was worth asking. Thanks!

Comment: I should mention the special case of `filter` (which doesn't fit your question because of the 1/).  Two more possibilities: 1. sometimes the recursive definition can be expanded out to a closed-form expression  2. You can write your function in C code and call it via a MEX file.